# Mixing vertical alignments in a tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I know about *tabu,tabularx, array,* and the likes, but none of them seem to provide a satisfying answer to a remark made in the [*LaTeX Table Hints and Tips*](http://nepsweb.co.uk/docs/tableTricks.pdf) by Adrian P. Robson.  Quoting:

> In addition, `p{}` `m{}` and `b{}` formats cannot be successfully mixed in
>   the same table.

That's precisely what I want to do.  Graphically, I want this:

[image: Tab]

The two first columns are `p{}`'s or `X`'s if using *tabularx*, and the last one should simply be centered vertically.

I'm searching for a *simple* solution, the less hacky, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining *tabu* and *multirow* behaves as wished:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Appearance(as appropriate for style)}\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Comment on color,clarity and head(retention,color and texture)}\\
\hline
Expected:Runs from copper to dark brown. Long-lasting,
dense, rocky white to ivory head. Clarity is poor to good,
haze not unexpected. Effervescent.
& Comments: & \multirow{1}{*}{/3}\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjustedtbl]

This does not work solely with *multirow* and a normal *tabular*.

Comment: the command \begin{tabu} must end with \end{tabu}. It works with multirow and tabu. However, as you said manual intervention is required when you use \lipsum

Comment: Ah shoot, I missed the `\end{tabu}`; can you fix it, so that I can accept your answer?  And manual intervention is needed *only when `tabular` is used*, not with `tabu`.  I'm not sure it is by design, but at least, it does work this way.

Comment: i have edited fixed